# Pop-up window not positioning itself correctly in IE6

Tags: javascript, html

So I have code like:

```
<ul>
<li><FORM><INPUT class="eButton" type="button" value="stream1!" onClick="window.open('./CSI1.html','win1','width=400,height=200,left=0,top=100,screenX=0,screenY=100')"> </li>

<li><FORM><INPUT class="eButton" type="button" value="stream2!" onClick="window.open('./CSI2.html','win2','width=400,height=200,left=0,top=100,screenX=400,screenY=100')"></FORM></li>
</ul>
```

Why does IE pop out the second window right on top of the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE6 uses the `left` and `top` parameters (and ignores `screenX` and `screenY`), so make your `left` `400` as well (it's currently `0` in both...hence your overlap). It should look like this on your second one:

```
window.open('./CSI2.html','win2','width=400,height=200,left=400,top=100,screenX=400,screenY=100')
```

Comment: @Lord - yes, but it's `0` in both :)

Comment: yes, but your initial answer just said to use them, which wasn't really a correct solution. I see that you have updated now, though.